# How can I access field 1 value from this dictionary by using java script?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How can I access field 1 value from this dictionary by using javascript?

```
   var a= "channel":
           {
            "latitude":"1.0",
            "longitude":"2.0",
            "field 1":"34"
            }
```

Comment: Is the object structure fixed, or do you need to search through a potentially variable nested structure looking for the right field? EDIT for your edit: OK, that's a simplified object, but is it currently in a variable, or is it supposed to be a JSON string, or...? (And what happened to the outer curly brackets?)

Comment: Do you know how to call another process from Node.js? OK, then call this: `/usr/bin/env` passing it `'python3'`, `-c`, and `'import sys\nimport json\nobj = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())\nprint(json.dumps(obj["field 1"]))'` as arguments, and the string you get from JSON-encoding this object as stdin. Take the stdout and JSON-parse it. If you need to run this in a browser, you'll want to emscripten CPython or PyPy.

Comment: The only problem is that this isn't a dictionary, it's just a single key-value pair on its own. That isn't valid JavaScript syntax, and doesn't describe a valid JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var x = {
  "channel": {
    "latitude": "0.0",
    "longitude": "0.0",
    "field 1": "Y"
  }
}

console.log(x["channel"]["field 1"])
```